# How do I change the red text color to something else in the C++ extension settings window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the red text color to something else in this image? I've searched through the entirety of the Workspace Color Customisations and none seem to affect its appearance.

`"textPreformat.foreground"` seems to work on some settings windows but not this one. Just for reference, this particular window is the C++ extension settings window.

[image]

Comment: does the color change if you change the theme, have you asked at the extension repo

Comment: It does change if I change the theme to something else. For example, the colour changes to yellow if I set the theme to NightOwl.

I'm actually building my own theme and I can't for life of me get this color to change by myself. I've even went on to the NightOwl Github page and copied their theme code into mine to get it to change and everything changes EXCEPT this little thing which is strange. When install the theme from the marketplace it changes though.

Comment: which names of the NightOwl theme have the yellow color or which theme color is not set by the extension and thus uses the default light/dark/high-contrast setting

Comment: I'm not sure, I've downloaded the entire NighOwl codebase from Github and scoured it looking for where the yellow is but couldn't find it. I'm thinking it may be set by something entirely different somewhere else but I can't seem to find where.

Comment: `Night Owl-color-theme.json` is the file you need

Comment: I know. As I've said, not a single one of those colour customisations in that file change the colour I'm trying to change. I've even copied the entire contents of that file into mine and everything changes except the red bits.

Comment: in webview the `<code>` tag content has a red color, use the webview dev tools to see where the red is defined